# ¿Tengo que definir los parametros que le voy a pasar a una función? Si no, ¿cómo podría resolver esto?

Tags: nodejs, express, passport

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de youtube para un login en node y me estanqué en una parte que hago algo diferente ya que uso bases de datos diferentes.

La cosa es que tengo que pasar la password y un usuario a una función que compara passwords, pero nunca llega el parametro y me dice:

Error: user is not defined

Primero paso mi archivo donde levanto la información:

```
  module.exports.getUserByUsername = function (user, callback) {
  var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

  var params = {
    TableName: "Usuarios",
    KeyConditionExpression: "#us = :uuuu",
    ExpressionAttributeNames: {
      "#us": "username"
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues: {
      ":uuuu": user
    }
  };

  docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Unable to query. Error:", JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    } else {
      data.Items.forEach(function (item) {
        console.log(item.username + ": " + item.password);
        let user = item.username;
        console.log(user);
        return user;
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Esto en teoría está devolviendo un usuario, ¿no?

Y acá esta la función completa de getUsuario y comparePassword

```
USER.getUserByUsername(username, (err, user) => { //** LINEA 39
    if (err) throw err;
    if (!user) {
      return res.json({
        success: false,
        "msg": "Usuario no encontrado"
      });
    } else {
      User.comparePassword(password, user.password, (err, isMatch) => {
        console.log("Llegó a comparePassword")
        if (err) throw err;
        if (isMatch) {
          const token = jwt.sign(user, secret.secret, {
            expiresIn: 86400
          });
          res.json({
            success: true,
            token: 'JWT ' + token,
            user: {
              user: user.username,
              password: user.password,
              email: USER.email
            }
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

El error aparece en la linea 39 donde marqué con comentario

Comment: me parece que el error está en el primer user, ya que el parametro user lo estás pasando en la función flecha, intenta sin el prumer user, es decir así 
USER.getUserByUsername( (err, user) => { ..  y comenta si persiste el error

Comment: Ahora recibo un: "ExpressionAttributeValues must not be empty", eso entiendo que pasa cuando a dynamo se le pasa un valor vacio para hacer el query, así que según entiendo, el parametro nunca llegó, cosa que antes sí pero no salía de la función, muy raro todo.

Ahi edite, al final le pasaba el parametro "username" y con eso sí llega a hacer el query, el query devuelve algo pero nunca llego a comparePassword

Comment: En la definición de la función o método 'getUserByUsername', defines 2 parámetros, 'user' y 'callback', sin embargo, dentro del cuerpo de la función nunca usas el 'callback', ¿Por que no lo usas?